# Question About the Definition of a $\mathbb{C}-$algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, vector-spaces

In the 'Quick review of commutative algebra' chapter a $\mathbb{C}-$ algebra is defined as a commutative ring that contains $\mathbb{C}$ as a subset. I don't understand if these coordinate rings are vector spaces nor if a variety is supposed to be a vector space.

I was thinking of functions on a circle such that $x^{2}+y^{2}-1 = 0$, but I can't tell how $\mathbb{C}$ is a subset in the range of the functions restricted to the circle. I mean how can a point such as $(0,1)$ be defined to go to the entire complex plane such as $1+i$, and $0+i$, and $1+0i$ and everything?

Comment: $\Bbb C$ corresponds to the constant functions.

Comment: That's also a possibility. A $K$-algebra is a $K$-vector space with a $K$-bilinear product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $k$ denote a field. A $k-$algebra is a ring $A$ equipped with an inclusion map $k\to A$. This gives $A$ a structure of a ring equipped with a compatible $k-$vector space structure. In this case, we are taking $k=\mathbb{C}$. If you have an affine variety $X\subseteq \mathbb{A}^n_{\mathbb{C}}$, say with ideal $\mathfrak{a}=(f_1,\ldots, f_k)\subseteq \Bbb{C}[x_1,\ldots, x_n]$, then it has affine coordinate ring $A(X)=\Bbb{C}[x_1,\ldots, x_n]/\mathfrak{a}.$ As long as $\mathfrak{a}$ is a proper ideal, it cannot contain $\mathbb{C}\subseteq \mathbb{C}[x_1,\ldots, x_n]$, and it follows that there is also a copy of $\mathbb{C}$ embedded in $A(X)$ by the composition
$$ \mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}[x_1,\ldots, x_n]\to A(X).$$
It follows that $A(X)$ is a $\mathbb{C}-$algebra. As mentioned in the comments above, the correct way to think about this is as $A(X)$ describing the polynomial functions on $X$, and $\mathbb{C}$ being included as the constant functions on $X$. That is, $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}\subseteq A(X)$ corresponds to a function $f$ on $X$ so that for all $x\in X$, $f(x)=\lambda$.